# Is there any option to switch LUIS.ai UI to any other language than English?

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

We have supervisor for content of our LUIS model who is barely speaking English.

Is there any option to switch LUIS.ai UI to any other language than English? Preferably French.

Now we work in pair - one understands the UI the other one the content but it is not exactly what we want.

Answer (score 1):

@Ferdinand Fejskid just spoke to the LUIS team and localization of the LUIS website is currently not a feature that is available yet.

Comment: Thanks. "yet" means it is on the roadmap? Or not even on the roadmap yet?